# Web.config transformation for different websites

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-deployment, web-config-transform

I have one project for publishing two separate websites on different servers. Both websites is in different languages (En and tr). 
For web-deploy I want to change appsettings for different environments for Debug and Release (For both websites).
I added config files for transformations like this:
[image]

Appsetting in main Web.config:

```
<add key="WebsiteMainCulture" value="en-US"/>
```

The code in transformation files are accordingly like this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="WebsiteMainCulture" value="TR"
         xdt:Locator="Match(key)" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
  </appSettings>
```

I selected Web.TR.Debug.config and ran project, But I always get 'en-US' as WebsiteMainCulture.

```
string website_main_culture = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebsiteMainCulture"].ToString(); // always en-US
```

Please help. Is there any better approach suggested for same environment?

Thanks!

Comment: I checked it by right clicking  and preview transform. It has transformed the value. but why Its not available in code.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for the problems I asked, also related to my previous question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612865/selecting-correct-seed-method-for-particular-language
I just added config transformation files by right clicking, to relevant publish(web deploy) files.Then added desired values to keys. And it worked.

[image]

Here are config transformation file auto generated.

[image]